# left statement doesn't work properly in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, locate

I used left statement and Locate to fet substring of some field in database to do (Show more). It is working properly but sometimes it's not working right.

This is the code :

```
function split_field($table = "d_book", $field = "bo_about", $length = 195) {
            $tbl_field = "TRIM(".$table.".".$field.")";       
            $sql = "CONCAT(LEFT({$tbl_field}, IF(LENGTH({$tbl_field}) > {$length}, LOCATE(' ', {$tbl_field}, {$length}), {$length})), 
                           IF(LENGTH({$tbl_field}) > {$length}, '...', ''))
                    AS `{$field}`";

            return $sql;

    }

$sql = "SELECT `bo_price`,`bo_id`, `bo_au_id`,`bo_name`,";
$sql .= split_field();
$sql .=",`bo_cover_img`, `bo_num_pages`, `d_book`.`bo_sec_id`, `d_section`.`sec_id`,         `d_author`.`au_id`, `d_author`.`au_name`        
                FROM (`d_book`) 
                JOIN `d_section` ON `d_section`.`sec_id`=`d_book`.`bo_sec_id` 
                JOIN `d_author` ON `d_author`.`au_id`=`d_book`.`bo_au_id` 
                WHERE `d_book`.`bo_state` = '1'";
$sql .= " ORDER BY `d_book`.`bo_ord` DESC LIMIT $start_limit,20";
```

The problem is that some books that have string less than 195 don't appear totally.

Tip: all strings in arabic language

Comment: can you paste here the final SQL pls?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what your problem is, but since you mention Arabic strings I suspect you may be using a multi-byte character set?  In which case, you probably want to use [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) (which returns the number of *characters* in a string) instead of [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_length) (which returns the number of *bytes* required to encode a string).

Comment: Thank you alot :) .. I changed it as you say and it's working now properly .. the proplem was in arabic .. put this comment in separate post to rate it